# How to transform series in a column to list in a column in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

i have a column that has a series of words and i need to transform it to a list and assign to the same column. I tried with a for loop but it has so many lines it takes too long

Here's the dataset:

```
   name      hobbies
0  James     "study","play"
1  Harden    "dance,"jump"
```

And i need to transform it to:

```
   name    hobbies
0  James   ["study","play"]
1  Harden  ["dance","jump"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df['hobbies'] = df['hobbies'].str.split(',')
```